# Ordering a string based on a number in each of its words

Tags: javascript, sorting

I am trying this question from Codewars.

It requires me to to sort a string based on the number in each of the words.

Sighted as follows:
Your task is to sort a given string. Each word in the string will contain a single number. This number is the position the word should have in the result.

Note: Numbers can be from 1 to 9. So 1 will be the first word (not 0).

If the input string is empty, return an empty string. The words in the input String will only contain valid consecutive numbers.

```
    Examples
    "is2 Thi1s T4est 3a"  -->  "Thi1s is2 3a T4est"
    "4of Fo1r pe6ople g3ood th5e the2"  -->  "Fo1r the2 g3ood 4of th5e pe6ople"
    ""  -->  ""
```

I found this solution online.

```
    function order(words){
      
      return words.split(' ').sort(function(a,b){
        return a.match(/\d/) - b.match(/\d/);
      }).join(' ');
    }
```

I did not understand the second nested function with the regex, someone kindly explain to me how it works.

Comment: What don't you understand about that function? Is it what `sort` expects to be passed as a callback? What the regex `/\d/` means? What `a` and `b` represent? Something else? Please make your question more focused.

Comment: Have you checked [String.prototype.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) docs? In this case, the sort function basically compares numbers specific for each sorted word: "2" for "is2", "4" for "4of" etc. But because it's `-` operator used, strings get cast to numbers basically.

Comment: The `function (a, b)` is being passed to [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#parameters) as its compareFn.

Comment: if the subtraction result is a positive integer, sort a after b. if it is a negative integer, sort b after a. if result is zero, mantain the same position. There's a crystal-clear table explaining this on the MDN link provided in the above comment.

Comment: You can debug what is happening `console.log(\`${a} ${b} \t ${a.match(/\d/)} - ${b.match(/\d/)} = ${a.match(/\d/) - b.match(/\d/)}\`);`

Answer (score 0):

To better understand the function, let's just take it apart piece by piece:

1. what means the regex `/\d/`? -> this just means the digits 0 - 9.
2. what means `match(/\d/)` here? -> this returns the **first** digit in the given string
3. why `return a.match(/\d/) - b.match(/\d/)`? -> because we want to sort the array of words by the numbers in the words ascending, we subtract the first from the second and returne the result.

**Summary:**
the second functions gets the first digit in a word, subtracts it from the following word and then sorts the the array ascending [1, 2, 3, 4, ...] so the words get in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

```
let text = '4of Fo1r pe6ople g3ood th5e the2'
let words = text.split(' ')
console.log(words)
// ["4of", "Fo1r", "pe6ople", "g3ood", "th5e", "the2"] 
let a = words[0]
console.log(a) // "4of"
console.log(a.match(/\d/)) // ["4"]

// and the hack is that
console.log(Number( ["4"] )) // it's 4 !!!
// minus casts values to numbers:
console.log(["4"] - ["1"]) // 3
// which is used for sorting
console.log('pe6ople'.match(/\d/) - 'g3ood'.match(/\d/)) // ["6"] - ["3"] = 3
```